# Suggested pattern for determining REST response type in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, response

We're trying to determine the type of the request being sent to our service so we can return the data in the proper format. The code below works perfectly, except we would like to avoid having to place it in the "Get" method of every single service that we create. Can anyone offer any suggestions as to how we could implement any sort of base class or extensibility point so that we don't have to copy and paste this snippet everywhere?

```
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Case/{id}")]
    public SampleItem Get(string id)
    {
        string formatQueryStringValue = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters["format"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formatQueryStringValue))
        {
            if (formatQueryStringValue.Equals("xml", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Xml;
            }
            else if (formatQueryStringValue.Equals("json", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new WebFaultException<string>(string.Format("Unsupported format '{0}'", formatQueryStringValue), HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }

        return new SampleItem() { StringValue = "test" };
    }
```

Comment: If you are on .NET 4 then the framework would determine the content-type the client understands and sends the response in that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the consumer to be able to specify their format via the
>   'format' query string parameter

You can use a message handler to look at the query string and add the accept header so that the rest of the processing works. In the following post the headers are being changed. I have also seen several demos of this on the internet and they may still be part of the contacts sample

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers